# Extraer datos de string xml como respuesta en Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, parsear

tengo el siguiente XML en un string y necesito extraer los nombres de la etiqueta "col"
Estoy intentando aprender a parsear pero no he podido dar en el clavo.
No se como iterarlo para extraer los datos de dicha etiqueta.
por favor si me pueden hechar una mano.
Muchas gracias

Este es mi código:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <processOXIMessageResponse xmlns="urn:com:singun:webservice" xmlns:ns="urn:com:singun:webservice">
         <ns1:processOXIMessageReturn xmlns:ns1="urn:com:singun:webservice">
            <SingunDocument xmlns="C" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" protocol="OXI">
               <sessionId xmlns="">1613762599483</sessionId>
               <command xmlns="" echo="" xsi:type="ServiceProviderGetListResponse">
                  <serviceProviderTable>
                     <colHeading>Service Provider Id</colHeading>
                     <colHeading>Service Provider Name</colHeading>
                     <colHeading>Is Enterprise</colHeading>
                     <colHeading>Reseller Id</colHeading>
                     <row>
                        <col>Fluk-TEST</col>
                        <col>ATP 1</col>
                        <col>true</col>
                        <col />
                     </row>
                     <row>
                        <col>Beltran-TEST</col>
                        <col>ATP 2</col>
                        <col>true</col>
                        <col />
                     </row>
                     <row>
                        <col>ACME-TEST</col>
                        <col>ATP 3</col>
                        <col>true</col>
                        <col />
                     </row>
                  </serviceProviderTable>
               </command>
            </SingunDocument>
         </ns1:processOXIMessageReturn>
      </processOXIMessageResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
'''
myroot = ET.fromstring(data)

print("\nRecupera todas las etiquetas de primer hijo de la raíz:")
for x in myroot[0]:
    print(x.tag, x.attrib)
```

Un saludo

Comment: Por ejemplo quiero extraer el siguiente dato:  /soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/processOXIMessageResponse/ns1:processOXIMessageReturn/SingunDocument/command/serviceProviderTable/row[1]/col[1]

Comment: Hasta el siguiente dato: /soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/processOXIMessageResponse/ns1:processOXIMessageReturn/SingunDocument/command/serviceProviderTable/row[3]/col[4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma un poco *burda* de parsear ese XML puede ser con por los elementos numéricos de cada nivel y finalmente con `findall()`:

```
root = ET.fromstring(data)
elements = root[0][0][0][0][1][0]
for row in elements.findall('row'):
    print("== NUEVA FILA ==")
    for col in row:
        print(col.text)
```

Una forma un poco más elegante y bonita de hacer lo mismo es con `iter()`

```
root = ET.fromstring(data)
for row in root.iter('row'):
    print("== NUEVA FILA ==")
    for col in row:
        print(col.text)
```

Leer [documentación del Parser XML](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). Para ambos casos, la salida es:

> ```
> == NUEVA FILA ==
> Fluk-TEST
> ATP 1
> true
> None
> == NUEVA FILA ==
> Beltran-TEST
> ATP 2
> true
> None
> == NUEVA FILA ==
> ACME-TEST
> ATP 3
> true
> None
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias @aeportugal , ha sido de mucha utilidad tu respuesta.